# How to print a pre formatted text in java

Tags: java-6, java1.4

i have string like this

```
                                                           31/12/2002

      HINDUSTHAN MOTORS LIMITED


       THREE LACS SEVENTY SEVEN THOUSAND THREE HUNDRED
       EIGHTY SEVEN ONLY

                                                            **377387.00
```

I want to print it in pre-printed cheque.

how to print this pre-formatted text in java.

I have text file which contains the above pre formatted text
my problem is the extension of the file is different (.kris format)
when I open the file in text doc the formatted text becomes one single line.

So, one single line printing in the printer is not acceptable.
I want to send above text to the printer by using the above fixed format.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download blank cheque template in word format (This is the toughest task I would say if you are searching for free template).
2.Replace labels in it by blank spaces(Make sure that blank spaces occupy same number of spaces as labels).
3.In place of values put some identifiers.for ex: in your case,in place of **377387.00 put **$amount,$date in place of date.
4.Save word as pdf.
5.Now with itext in java replace $ values by your actual values.(itext library in java is used to handle pdfs).
Take print and check if it comes properly on blank cheque else do some minor changes to re-align them.